# How do I migrate my JPA DAO to Spring Data with second level cache?

Tags: spring, jpa, caching, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I have bunch of JPA DAOs im looking to migrate to Spring Data JPA. Some of my DAOS have second-level / query caching set up.

I have a process where I only retrieve the ID in my queries, and then look up the entity using `findByID()`. This way, only the id's are multiplied in the different query caches, and the entire entities are in the second level cache.

Example:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "SystemUser.findByEmail",
            query = "SELECT u.id FROM SystemUser u WHERE email=:email"),
…

public SystemUser findByEmail(String email) {

    TypedQuery<Long> q = getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("SystemUser.findByEmail", Long.class);
    q.setParameter("email", email);
    q.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheable", true);
    q.setHint("org.hibernate.cacheRegion", "query.systemUser");

    List<Long> res = q.getResultList();

    if (res != null && res.size() > 0) {
        return findById(res.get(0));
    }

    return null;
}
```

I have several more `findBy…`-methods, all doing it like this. It feels like a good way to keep cache memory consumption down.

I'm kind of new to the Spring Data JPA business, but I can't see how I would go about realizing this here? The `@Cacheable` annotations seems only to deal with query caches, which to me would duplicate the entities in each query cache?

Is there any way to do this with Spring Data? Pointers would be much appreciated.

Comment: `@Cacheable` has nothing to do with query or 2nd level caching. It is about caching the results of of a method invocation and works with or without hibernate. You could also use it to cache results of long computations for instance. Also your code seems needlessly complex why not simply return the `SystemUser` instead of doing 2 queries for which you could have fired a single query. Looks like a premature optimization gone wrong?

Comment: Say i have 5 methods in Systemuser all doing "findby..." different params, all cached. With my solution, only the id's are stored in each query cache, and  only one 'full' systemuser instance is stored, in the second level cache, which all 5 methods would retrieve by findById. I hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 4):

In Spring Data JPA just create a [`findByEmail`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-lookup-strategies) method and either Spring Data JPA will found your named query or create one itself.

```
public class SystemUserRepository extends CrudRepository<SystemUser, Long> {

    SystemUser findByEmail(String email);
}
```

Should be all you need to get the query executed and the desired result. Now with the [`@QueryHints`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-hints) you can add the hints you are setting now.

```
public class SystemUserRepository extends CrudRepository<SystemUser, Long> {

    @QueryHints(
        @QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheable", value="true"),
        @QueryHint(name="org.hibernate.cacheRegion", value="query.systemUser")        )
    SystemUser findByEmail(String email);
}
```

The result will be cached and still the user will come from the 2nd level cache (if available, else created). Assuming of course your entity is `@Cacheable`.

A nice read on how the 2 different caches work (together) can be found [here](http://blog.jhades.org/setup-and-gotchas-of-the-hibernate-second-level-and-query-caches/). A small snippet on how the query cache works.

> The query cache looks conceptually like an hash map where the key is composed by the query text and the parameter values, and **the value is a list of entity Id's that match the query**:

If you want more complex logic (and really implement the optimization you did) you can always implement your [own repository](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-behaviour-for-all-repositories).

Comment: Hey thanks for quick response. I have a repository solution up and running, but as you mentioned, my previous caching solution is not. Great to hear about @queryhints, but as you said, won't help me with my caching performance tweak, i'd have to have each query load all the data, resulting in the data duplicated for each region's query cache. So the only way is to implement my own repository? OK... :)

Comment: The result of the query is cached, the actual user instances should still come from the general cache. The only difference is you cache maybe a little less however introduce overhead due to additional queries, which might even be worse when you do something this with multiple results as that effectively leads to the 1+N select problem. (1 query for the ids, another query for each row to get the full results). IMHO you are trying to optimize something but are introducing more problems and complexity then you are trying to solve.

Comment: The only time there's an additional query is the first time, the other times it will be in the second level cache. I know about the 1+n problem, which is why we only do it for unique results. For those, we've noticed memory and performance improvements.

Comment: Not sure what you mean "the actual user instances comes from the general cache"? Surely a cached "select id from X where"-query takes way less memory than a "select a, b, c, d, e, f, g, h from X where"?

Comment: Your optimizations don't make sense as the entities are cached in the 2nd level cache even without the `findById`.. So imho you only complicated things, the query cache stores the query results (actually the identifiers!) and not the entities. Have you actually measured this or are just thinking it is better? Does it really matter so much? I strongly suggest you measure things before optimizing and making things more complex. Hibernate and the cache are really smart in optimizing what is stored in memory.

Comment: I strongly suggest a read of [this](http://blog.jhades.org/setup-and-gotchas-of-the-hibernate-second-level-and-query-caches/) which explains what is cached and how. And basically the query cache already stores the id only... So as you can so you are trying to optimize something that is already optimized and you need it to optimize because you are writing your own queries. Basically the repository method as shown in the answer should work as well as your own homegrown optimized solution.

Comment: You might be right that its not worth it, also this code has been around for a while, possibly from a time where the optimisation made more sense (which is why we're looking at updating). However, there's more to it than just the string in the query cache - just fetching the id from the database rather than full, large objects is less taxing both on memory, network traffic and database processing.

Comment: Please read the blog I added. When doing the correct queries, hibernate only caches the id and then the optimization don't make any sense. A query like `FROM SystemUser u where u.emailAddress=?` would only cache the id NOT the full result set. That is what I'm trying to explain. And the query that Spring Data JPA is generating is exactly that query...

Comment: ...And i understand that. However the converted native sql will still fetch all data from DB vs just the id's if not cached, which makes a difference. That's what i was saying. I have tried it. Thanks for your valuable pointers!

Comment: Well yes but that could be even faster then your optimized solution. The query will only be executed once, after that the ids of the matching entities are cached. In your case you always execute 2 queries, one for the ids and one for all the information. Without your you only have a single query instead of 2, which saves you a round trip... So I still highly question your optimized version as to me it still seems it complicates things rather than optimize it. IMHO a case of premature optimization. But that is from this side of the world.